# Android: RecyclerView Click Listener is not getting in Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have an array of 600 items. I have put all the array items in a RecyclerView and they are scrolling well. But, when I try to access onClick listener it is not getting called. I also tried to Implement View.OnClickListener and Override onClick in my ViewHolder class, but its not working.

I want to Toast data of the clicked item in the list when user clicks one of the items in the view

**Adapter code is**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements View.OnClickListener {
private String mItem;
private TextView mTextView;

public ViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
}

public void setItem(String item) {
    mItem = item;
    mTextView.setText(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onClick " + getPosition() + " " + mItem);
}
}

 private String[] mDataset;

 public MyAdapter(String[] dataset) {
  mDataset = dataset;
}

@Override
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
return vh;
  }

@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  holder.setItem(mDataset[position]);
  }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
 return mDataset.length;
 }
}
```

Comment: Show `R.layout.item` layout xml also

Comment: Easy method is in on bindviewholder you can set eachitemclicklistner

Comment: you must add `setOnclickListner` in `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try this..

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
           {
    private String mItem;
    private TextView mTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
      super(view);
      mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);


    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
      mItem = item;
      mTextView.setText(item);
    }

    private String[] mDataset;
Context context;
    public MyAdapter(Context context,String[] dataset) {
    this.context=context;
      mDataset = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
              .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
      ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
      return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.setOnClickListener(new ItemClicklistener(position);
      holder.setItem(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
      return mDataset.length;
    }


      class ItemClicklistener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private  int position;

        ItemClicklistener(int position) {

            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Toast.makeText(context,"OnClick :"+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
            private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
            private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;
            private List<MyModel> list; 
            View v1;
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;

            public MyAdapter(List<MyModel> lists) {
                list = lists;

            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                return list.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
            }

            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                              int viewType) {
                if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {

                    v1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                            R.layout.item, parent, false);
                    vh = new MyViewHolder(v1);
                    return vh;
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

                if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {

                   final MyModel mymodel= (MyModel) list.get(position);

                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).mTextView.setText(mymodel.getItem());

                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                             Log.d("TAG", "onClick " + Integer.toString(position) + " " + mymodel.getItem());
                        }
                    });

                }

            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return list.size();
            }


            public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

                public TextView;

                public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                    super(view);
                     mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                }
            }


        }


    // List Item Stored


    public class MyModel extends Application implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String item,

        public MyModel() {}

        public MyModel(String itemtext) {
            this.item = itemtext;
        }

        public String getItem() {return  item;}

        public void setItem(String id){ this.item = item;}


    }



//use this code in main activity

List<MyModel> Listitem = new ArrayList<CarListGetterSetter>();
for(int i=0;i<600;i++){
Listitem.add(new MyModel("hi"+i);
}

 RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
 MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(Listitem);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Stored Your List Item In MyModel Class And try this

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your RecyclerView adapter this way to support for onItemCLick and OnItemLongClick

```
public class PersonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonAdapter.ViewHolder>{

ArrayList<Person> data;
Context context;
HashMap<String, Integer> screenDetails;


private static ClickListener clickListener;

public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    void onItemLongClick(int position, View v);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    PersonAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{
    public View view;

    TextView full_name;


    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        view = v;

        full_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.first_name);

        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        return false;
    }
}


public PersonAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View cardView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_chatroom_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(cardView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Person person = data.get(position);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


}
```

And in your activity implement it this way

```
PersonAdapter personAdapter = new PersonAdapter(getApplicationContext(),persons);
    personAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new PersonAdapter.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(int position, View v) {

        }
    });
recyclerView.setAdapter(PersonAdapter);
```